# Is there a way to resolve multiple promises with Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have this:

```
element(by.id('x')).sendKeys('xxx').then(function(text) {
  element(by.id('y')).sendKeys('yyy').then(function(text) {
     element(by.id('z')).sendKeys('zzz').then(function(text) {
        expect(element(by.id('myButton')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);
     })
  });
});
```

The button 'myButton' is enabled when the elements 'x', 'y' and 'z' all have values. It's my understanding that sendKeys returns a promise.

So is this the only way that I can check if 'myButton' which depends on data in all the three fields is enabled?

Comment: You should probably accept Andres answer since that's correct.

Comment: completely changed my answer. found official support by protractor. please review and accept.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to chain any promises because protractor will wait until all the statements are done: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

```
element(by.id('x')).sendKeys('xxx');
element(by.id('y')).sendKeys('yyy');
element(by.id('z')).sendKeys('zzz');
expect(element(by.id('myButton'));
```

If you want to resolve multiple promises use:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
webdriver.promise.fullyResolved(promises);
```

For example: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d15d35a82a5a2/lib/protractor.js#L327

Answer (score 12):

this is a bit after the fact, but:

```
var x = element(by.id('x')).sendKeys('xxx');
var y = element(by.id('y')).sendKeys('yyy');
var z = element(by.id('z')).sendKeys('zzz');

myFun(x,y,z).then(function(){
   expect(element(by.id('myButton')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);
});


// in a common function library
function myFun(Xel,Yel,Zel) {
  return protractor.promise.all([Xel,Yel,Zel]).then(function(results){
     var xText = results[0];
     var yText = results[1];
     var zText = results[2];

  });
}
```

but an even better way:

```
var x = element(by.id('x')).sendKeys('xxx');
var y = element(by.id('y')).sendKeys('yyy');
var z = element(by.id('z')).sendKeys('zzz');

myFun(x,y,z);
//isEnabled() is contained in the expect() function, so it'll wait for
// myFun() promise to be fulfilled
expect(element(by.id('myButton')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);


// in a common function library
function myFun(Xel,Yel,Zel) {
  return protractor.promise.all([Xel,Yel,Zel]).then(function(results){
     var xText = results[0];
     var yText = results[1];
     var zText = results[2];

  });
}
```

another way is to chain the .thens together:

```
element(by.id('x')).sendKeys('xxx').
  then(function(xtext){
    element(by.id('y')).sendKeys('yyy');

  }).then(function(ytext){
     element(by.id('z')).sendKeys('zzz');

  }).then(function(ztext){
    expect(element(by.id('myButton')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems protractor supports `all` - `protractor.promise.all`

read more at:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2062#issuecomment-94030055

```
describe('promise.all', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo');

    $('div').click().then(function () {
      return protractor.promise.all([
          $('h3').getText(),
          $('h4').getText()
      ]);
    }).then(function (params) {
      console.log('A');
    });
  });

  it('does something else', function() {
    console.log('B');
  });
```

If you want to return an object instead of a list, seems you can also do that - used it and it's awesome

```
element.all(by.css('.fc-event-inner')).map(function(el) {
  return {
    time: el.findElement(by.className('fc-event-time')).getText(),
    title: el.findElement(by.className('fc-event-title')).getText()
  }
});
```

See the properties are actually promises.. protractor will resolve them.

Comment: thank you, really didn't want to use requirejs just for this method

Comment: @jrhee17 If you want to return an object instead of list you can also do that easily: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/392#issuecomment-33237672